# C# mimic Java generic?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

In Java this is valid:

```
class Class1<T extends OtherType> { T t; ... }

//Inside other class that has no relation to Class1
private Class1 class1; //No type needed

public void someOtherFunction (Class1 class1) //Works  
{  
    this.class1 = class1; //May warn about invalid type casting
    class1.someFunction();
}
```

C# demands a type under the same conditions:

```
class Class1<T> where T : OtherType { T t; ... }

//Inside other class that has no relation to Class1
private Class1<TYPE DEMANDED> class1; //I don't know generic what type, and honestly it doesn't matter.

public void someOtherFunction (Class1 class1) //This is the definition I want to use, but C# Demands a type to class1 
public void someOtherFunction<T> (Class1<T> class1) where T : OtherType //C# Demands a type to class1 so I must specify a T
{  
    this.class1 = class1;
    class1.someFunction();
} //This function is valid but then it still needs the type to store it.
```

Is there any way to omit the type? It isn't necessary to know the type so why is it required? I can't make `Class1` of type `OtherType`, because the point of the generic is to have an unknown type that extends the base of `OtherType`. I can work around it, but this is definitely the most efficient solution, if it were Java and I will have to type cast once a frame for multiple objects if this does not work, which I am worried will add up fast.

Actual code, per request:

```
public abstract class Weapon { ... }

public abstract class WeaponProxy<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Weapon
{
    protected T weapon;

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        ...
        holdingPlayer = player.getHUD().showPickup(player, this);
        ...
    } 

public abstract class GunProxy<T> : WeaponProxy<T> where T : Gun
{

}



public abstract class Weapon
{
    private string weaponName;
    private string weaponIdentifier;
    private Player isHolding;

    public string getWeaponName () { return weaponName; }
    public Weapon(string weaponName, string weaponIdentifier)
    {
        this.weaponName = weaponName;
        this.weaponIdentifier = weaponIdentifier;
    }

    public void playerPickedUp (Player player)
    {
        this.isHolding = player;
    }

    public void playerDropped ()
    {
        this.isHolding = null;
    }
}

public class Gun : Weapon
{
  ...
}

public class HUD : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WeaponProxy weapon; //C# Needs a type. Underlined in red as error   

    public PlayerProxy showPickup<T> (PlayerProxy player, WeaponProxy<T> weapon) where T : Weapon
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
        textPickupWeapon.text = "Hold '" + player.getPlayer().getControlScheme().getControlText(ControlScheme.CONTROLS.Interact) + "' to pick up " + weapon.getWeapon().getWeaponName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `class` and `object` are reserved in C#; do not use them as a variable name.

Comment: @EricLippert I am aware, Ill fix that now. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how Java works, but in .NET, generic types with different type parameters are actually different types. These "constructed generic types" are generated by the compiler, so, the type parameter must be known at compile time. So I don't think using it the way you write it is possible. For more info see MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Since `someFunction` uses `T` what kind of magic you expect for it to know the type? (If `someFunction` does not use `T` it would be in non-generic base class of `Class1<T>`, so I think my assumption is reasonable)

Comment: Are you actually looking to implement a generic class, or do you want to implement a class that derives from a generic?

Comment: @amg-argh, I'm looking to implement a generic class.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov someFunction only uses T because VS is telling me Class1 must have a type. So I have to include T. Ideally it wouldn't at all, as the function definition above it decribes

Comment: @AndrewNo are you sure? If you don't care what the type is, why do you just not take an "object" as a parameter to its function? Or OtherType?

Comment: @amg-argh, because Class1 and OtherType are both superclasses that both have descendents. I tried accepting OtherType as the Generic, but then in Class1, I can't call somefunction because T is not soley OtherType, it is something that is or extends it. object also does neither :/

Comment: @AndrewNo If you accept `OtherType` any type derived from `OtherType` is acceptable

Comment: @amg-argh, That is what I thought, but I get the following error: "Cannot convert argument1 from 'T' to OtherType, which doesn't make sense because T must extend from OtherType.

Comment: @AndrewNo could you edit your post, with exactly the code you currently have that produces this error? After reading your question multiple times and your comments, I still don't understand 100% what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewNo does `public class GunProxy : WeaponProxy<Gun>` allow it to work for you? Then as your parameter you take `WeaponProxy<Gun>` and you can accept `GunProxy`

Comment: @amg-argh, I actually only included GunProxy as an example. The problem lies in the WeaponProxy - HUD relationship, but the code you provided does work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your java code is "valid" because all generics in java are actually non-generics, since java's generics are only a compile time trick, with no runtime support whatsoever.

For the java runtime, type `A<T>` is actually `A` with no type parameters, because the java runtime doesn't actually support generics at all.

In contrast, the .NET CLR has built-in support for runtime generic types, and hence it differentiates between a type `A` and a generic type `A<T>`.

In C#, if you want a non-generic version of type `Class1`, simply declare it:

```
class Class1
{
    //Whatever members that don't require a type parameter,

    void SomeFunction() { /* ... */ } // Please use proper casing.
}
```

then, if you need a generic version of this class:

```
class Class1<T>: Class1
{
    T Content { get; set; }
}
```

Now you will be able to have a member of type `Class1` in any other class

```
class Example
{
    Class1 instance; // Valid

    public void someOtherFunction (Class1 class1) //Works  
    {  
        this.instance = class1; //Does not warn about anything because this is type safe.
        class1.SomeFunction(); // Works

        var content = class1.Content // Compile Error: type class1 does not have such member "Content"
    }
}
```

Notice how the C# approach is much safer, if you're using the non generic version, you can only access class members that are defined in the non generic version and do not require a type parameter. In contrast, java is totally unsafe, and may produce horrible runtime errors due to lack of real type safety in generics.

Comment: @AndrewNo I'm looking at the code you just added to your question, and I don't think it's going to take much of a rewrite. I don't even think it takes generics. Simply an interface. All Players should be an `IPlayer`, and all Weapons should be an `IWeapon`.

Comment: @mason, Actually, this is not equivalent, because T would have to be declared as a variable in the non generic class, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @mason, an Interface! I didn't think of that. I'll make changes, and report back in a bit. Thank you.

Comment: @mason, Interfaces didn't work. Ill update my question as to why.

Comment: @AndrewNo I suggest you make a new question. You've already asked this one and received a great answer from HighCore. Make a new question if you're still confused. Just because you had an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) doesn't mean you should change this question.

Comment: @mason, I understand, but this answer does not fix the problem. Ill add more of my code to explain why.

Comment: @AndrewNo It solved the original question you asked, which I presume is why you accepted the answer (I believe you accepted and then unaccepted it?). You've now got a new question to ask, so do the correct thing and ask a new question rather than changing this one.

Comment: @mason, I did mark it as correct because at first glance, I thought it would work, but as T is crucial to the class, a generic class that extends the non generic one does not work.

Comment: @AndrewNo That's fine, but ask a *new question* as HighCore already answered your original question. It's not fair to him to change the question after he's already written an answer.

Comment: @mason, Will do. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewNo more discussion on changing existing question if you interested - [Chameleon question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer)